# Can I remove the "summary" from the "Text (formatted, long, with summary)" widget?

Tags: 8, entities

When creating a new content type, by default it has the **Body** field, which has a **Field type** of *Text (formatted, long, with summary)*.  For this content type, I don't want authenticated users to see the summary.

What's the proper way to hide the "edit summary" part for non-admin users?  Or, am I better off deleting the default **Body** field and creating a new custom field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that was easy.  On admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields/mycontenttype, you just have to uncheck the box for "Summary input."

Answer (score 0):

### For those who may be looking for the D7 version of @Patrick Kenny 's answer:

```
https://{{mysite.foobar.com}}/admin/structure/types/manage/{{mycontenttype}}/fields/body
```